# Add condition into PHP email send

Tags: php, html, email, loops, concatenation

I am creating an email using PHP, but I need to add a PHP loop and conditional statements into it. Here's my code:

```
$message = '
<table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
  <tr>
    <td height="50"><strong>Shipping address</strong>
    <p>'.$showDelivery['first_name']." ".$showDelivery['surname'].'</p>
    <p>'.$showDelivery['address1'].'</p>
    <p>'.$showDelivery['address2'].'</p>
    <p>'.$showDelivery['address3'].'</p>
    <p>'.$showDelivery['town'].'</p>
    <p>'.$showDelivery['county'].'</p>
    <p>'.$showDelivery['postcode'].'</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p><strong>Shipping Date</strong> '.$monthName = date("F", mktime(0, 0, 0, $show['shipping_month'], 10)) . " ".$show['shipping_day']." ".$show['shipping_time'].'</p>
    </td>
    <td width="150" height="50">'.if($show['number_of_people'] == 0) {     $show['number_of_people']; }."</td>
</tr>
</table>';
```

I have added the conditional in above in the last table data but it doesn't run.

Can anyone help?

Many thanks!

Comment: `.($show['number_of_people'] == 0 ? $show['number_of_people'] : '').` try this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have put `if` in your string, which is not right.

Try this way...

```
$message = '
<table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
  <tr>
    <td height="50"><strong>Shipping address</strong>
    <p>'.$showDelivery['first_name']." ".$showDelivery['surname'].'</p>
    <p>'.$showDelivery['address1'].'</p>
    <p>'.$showDelivery['address2'].'</p>
    <p>'.$showDelivery['address3'].'</p>
    <p>'.$showDelivery['town'].'</p>
    <p>'.$showDelivery['county'].'</p>
    <p>'.$showDelivery['postcode'].'</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p><strong>Shipping Date</strong> '.$monthName = date("F", mktime(0, 0, 0, $show['shipping_month'], 10)) . " ".$show['shipping_day']." ".$show['shipping_time'].'</p>
    </td>
    <td width="150" height="50">';

if($show['number_of_people'] == 0) {     
    $message .= $show['number_of_people']; 
}

$message .=.'</td>
</tr>
</table>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't concat a `if()` with a string.
do you if before you file `$message`, then add the variable to you `$message`.

Exemple :

```
$number = ($show['number_of_people'] == 0) ? $show['number_of_people'] : '';
$message = '.......<td>'.$number.'</td>......';
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming what your trying to do is echo out the variable $show, then you need to place the echo function into your code.

```
if($show['number_of_people'] == 0) {     $show['number_of_people']; }
```

Should be

```
if($show['number_of_people'] == 0) {   echo $show['number_of_people']; }
```

Answer (score 0):

you could declare it as a variable before you start.

```
$showPeople = '';
if($show['number_of_people'] === 0){ 
   $showPeople = $show['number_of_people']; 
}

$message = '
<table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
  <tr>
    <td height="50"><strong>Shipping address</strong>
    <p>'.$showDelivery['first_name']." ".$showDelivery['surname'].'</p>
    <p>'.$showDelivery['address1'].'</p>
    <p>'.$showDelivery['address2'].'</p>
    <p>'.$showDelivery['address3'].'</p>
    <p>'.$showDelivery['town'].'</p>
    <p>'.$showDelivery['county'].'</p>
    <p>'.$showDelivery['postcode'].'</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p><strong>Shipping Date</strong> '.$monthName = date("F", mktime(0, 0, 0,  
        $show['shipping_month'], 10)) . " ".$show['shipping_day']."
        ".$show['shipping_time'].'</p>
    </td>
    <td width="150" height="50">'. $showPeople ."</td>
</tr>
</table>';
```